# Is there a way to create a named scope that groups?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, group-by, named-scope

I have the following using searchlogic:

```
@todos = Todo.contact_user_id_is(current_user).
              contact_campaign_id_is(@campaign).
              current_date_lte(Date.today).
              done_date_null.
              ascend_by_current_date
```

I only want @todos to contain a Todo record for a single contact_id (contact_id is an attribute on Todo).

Question: how can I group so that I there is only one record per contact_id in the @todos array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`named_scope` supports grouping. Something like this should work:

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :contact

  named_scope :one_per_contact, lambda{ |user, campaign|
    {
      :joins => :contact,
      :conditions => ['contacts.user_id = ? AND contacts.campaign_id = ? AND todos.current_date <= ? AND todos.done_date IS NULL', user.id, campaign.id, Date.today],
      :group => 'todos.contact_id'
      :order => :current_date
    }
  }

end
```

Then just put this in your controller:

```
@todos = Todo.one_per_contact(current_user, @campaign)
```

The code may not be exactly right for your app, but you get the idea.

Comment: lemme give it a go I'll send you the outcome...man, still trying to understand lambdas

Comment: Hi, so I notice this uses conditions for user and campaign -- but the searchlogic named scopes already do that....so I still need those for this additional named scope to work?

Comment: This named scope should work without any extra searchlogic scopes. But you could also remove those conditions and chain the searchlogic named scopes instead. In this case though, I'd keep it all in the named scope, since it performs a pretty specific function.

Comment: Hi, I removed the :conditions but it didn't seem to reduce the number of contact_id's to just one instance....I also removed the lambda since I don't need that function to do the group, is that correct?

Comment: I ended up using statistics gem